# Can I find a method with generic parameters using strongly typed reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Here's my attempt at calling an existing generic method with a type argument.  '*Strongly typed reflection*' may not be a suitable term, but it basically means finding and invoking the reflected method without using a name string.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test(Type type)
    {
        InvokeTestMethodWithType(type);
    }

    private void Test<T>() { ... }

    private static void InvokeTestMethodWithType(Type type)
    {
        // This doesn't compile! - can I find Test<> using this approach?
        Expression<Func<TestClass, Action>> ex = x => x.Test<>;

        // invoke it
        ((MethodCallExpression)ex.Body).Method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(new TestClass(), null);
    }
}
```

Sample call would end up call the private Test().

```
TestClass.Test(typeof(Foo))
```

As you can see, I'm struggling with the expression and not entirely sure if it can be executed in this manner.

Do I have to dummy invoke the action in the expression like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959129/find-methodinfo-for-method-of-generic-class-using-strongly-typed-reflection-wit)?

```
x => x.Test<object>()
```

Comment: What if you made `InvokeTestMethodWithType` expect a generic type?

Comment: @NielsFilter I would if I could but it's only known at runtime from a type mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick I use is simple: pass a fake generic type argument:

```
Expression<Func<TestClass, WhateverTestReturns>> ex = x => x.Test<string>();

// invoke it
((MethodCallExpression)ex.Body)
  .Method
  .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
  .MakeGenericMethod(type)
  .Invoke(new TestClass(), null);
```

The method call expression will then contain a method info for `Test<string>()`, but you can easily use `GetGenericMethodDefinition` to remove the generic argument, and then `MakeGenericMethod` to put a different one back in its place.

You don't even need to use `Expression` in a case like this - simply cast `TestClass.Test<string>` to a delegate, and you'll have a `Method` property that gives you the same method info.

Comment: +1 Brilliant, thanks for the nod towards `GetGenericMethodDefinition()` and using Delegate.  Re-written to use Delegate and works like a charm.