# How do I call a parameterless generic method from Powershell v3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

For example I have a .NET object `$m` with the following method overloads:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> $m.GetBody

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------    
T GetBody[T]() 
T GetBody[T](System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
```

If I try to invoke the parameterless method I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> $m.GetBody()
Cannot find an overload for "GetBody" and the argument count: "0".
At line:1 char:1
+ $m.GetBody()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I understand PowerShell v3.0 is supposed to work more easily with generics. Obviously I need to tell it somehow what type I want returned but I cannot figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like you are trying to invoke a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

In powershell this can be done by:

```
$nonGenericClass = New-Object NonGenericClass
$method = [NonGenericClass].GetMethod("SimpleGenericMethod")
$gMethod = $method.MakeGenericMethod([string]) 
# replace [string] with the type you want to use for T. 
$gMethod.Invoke($nonGenericClass, "Welcome!")
```

See [this](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/06/19/invoking-generic-methods-on-non-generic-classes-in-powershell/) wonderful blog post for more info and additional examples.

For your example you could try:

```
$Source = @" 
public class TestClass
{
    public T Test<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    public int X;
}
"@ 

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 
$obj = New-Object TestClass

$Type  = $obj.GetType();
$m =  $Type.GetMethod("Test")
$g = new-object system.Guid
$gType = $g.GetType()
$gm = $m.MakeGenericMethod($gType)
$out = $gm.Invoke( $obj, $null)
#$out will be the default GUID (all zeros)
```

This can be simplified by doing:

```
$Type.GetMethod("Test").MakeGenericMethod($gType).Invoke( $obj, $null)
```

This has been testing in powershell 2 and powershell 3.

If you had a more detailed example of how you came across this generic method I would be able to give more details. I have yet to see any microsoft cmdlets return anything that give you generic methods. The only time this comes up is when custom objects or methods from c# or vb.net are used.

To use this without any parameters you can use Invoke with just the first parameter. 
    $gMethod.Invoke($nonGenericClass)

Comment: Yes, its a generic method as stated in the question title :) I'll update to clarify this is .NET object created with new-object. Lees post also claims in PSv3 you don't need any of that ugly stuff...the problem is the method I want to call has no input parameters hence T cannot be inferred.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still have to resort to using reflection in this scenario.  V3 improved consumption of generics but there still are some rough edges.

Comment: V3 only improves on creating generic objects such as a Generic List. I feel like if you really need generics, you should probably look into writing a console application that utilises powershell functions, however handles generics in C# or VB.net.

Comment: @Schneider , I am interested to know if this works for you. I did some more research to find that psv3 does not improve generic methods, just creating generic objects.

Comment: This answer and code sample does not answer OP which has a method with overloads. However the referenced article does explain how to handle overloads.

Answer (score 6):

Calling a generic method on an object **instance**:

```
$instance.GetType().GetMethod('MethodName').MakeGenericMethod([TargetType]).Invoke($instance, $parameters)
```

Calling a **static** generic method (see also [Calling generic static method in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241985)):

```
[ClassType].GetMethod('MethodName').MakeGenericMethod([TargetType]).Invoke($null, $parameters)
```

Note that you will encounter an `AmbiguousMatchException` when there is also a non-generic version of the method (see [How do I distinguish between generic and non generic signatures using GetMethod in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566613)). Use `GetMethods()` then:

```
([ClassType].GetMethods() | where {$_.Name -eq "MethodName" -and $_.IsGenericMethod})[0].MakeGenericMethod([TargetType]).Invoke($null, $parameters)
```

(Mind that there could be more than one method that match the above filter, so make sure to adjust it to find the one you need.)

*Hint: You can write complex generic type literals like this (see [Generic type of Generic Type in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975130)):*

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,string[]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a (parameterless) generic method *with overloads* from Powershell v3, as shown in the OP example, use the script Invoke-GenericMethod.ps1 from the reference provided by @Chad Carisch, [Invoking Generic Methods on Non-Generic Classes in PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/06/19/invoking-generic-methods-on-non-generic-classes-in-powershell/).

It should look something like

```
Invoke-GenericMethod $m GetBody T @()
```

This is a verified working code sample that I am using:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common") | Out-Null

$serviceLocator = [Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common.ServiceLocation.SharePointServiceLocator]::GetCurrent()

# Want the PowerShell equivalent of the following C#
# config = serviceLocator.GetInstance<IConfigManager>();

# Cannot find an overload for "GetInstance" and the argument count: "0".
#$config = $serviceLocator.GetInstance()

# Exception calling "GetMethod" with "1" argument(s): "Ambiguous match found."
#$config = $serviceLocator.GetType().GetMethod("GetInstance").MakeGenericMethod([IConfigManager]).Invoke($serviceLocator)

# Correct - using Invoke-GenericMethod
$config = C:\Projects\SPG2013\Main\Scripts\Invoke-GenericMethod $serviceLocator GetInstance Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common.Configuration.IConfigManager @()

$config.CanAccessFarmConfig
```

Here is an alternate script that I haven't tried but is more recent and being actively maintained, [Invoke Generic Methods from PowerShell](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Generic-Methods-bf7675af).

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: **PowerShell (Core) 7.3+** now ***does* support calling
generic methods with explicit type arguments**.

```bash
 # PS v7.3+ only; using [string] as an example type argument.
 $m.GetBody[string]()
```

- See the conceptual [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calling_Generic_Methods) help topic

---

**PowerShell (Core) 7.2- and Windows PowerShell:**

[marsze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36617613/45375) contains great general information about calling generic methods, but let me address the aspect of calling a *parameter-less* one specifically, as asked:

As hinted at in the question:

- **in PSv3+ PowerShell can *infer* the type from the *parameter values*** (arguments) passed to a generic method,
- which by definition **cannot work with a *parameter-less* generic method**, because there is nothing to infer the type *from*.

Prior to PowerShell (Core) 7.3, **PowerShell previously had *no* syntax that would allow you to specify the type explicitly in this scenario**.

In such older versions, **reflection must be used**:

```powershell
# Invoke $m.GetBody[T]() with [T] instantiated with type [decimal]
$m.GetType().GetMethod('GetBody', [type[]] @()).
    MakeGenericMethod([decimal]).
      Invoke($m, @())
```

- `.GetMethod('GetBody', [type[]] @())` unambiguously finds the *parameter-less* overload of`.GetBody()`, due to passing in an *empty array* of parameter types.
- `.MakeGenericMethod([decimal])` instantiates the method with example type `[decimal]`.
- `.Invoke($m, @())` then invokes the type-instantiated method on input object (`$m`) with no arguments (`@()`, the empty array).