# New-Object returns empty object

Tags: excel, powershell, openxml

I'm trying to extend [this example](http://hinchley.net/2016/02/06/read-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-using-powershell-and-the-open-xml-sdk/) using [extarnal module](https://github.com/dlwyatt/PSGenericMethods/blob/master/GenericMethods.psm1) to call generic methods. My goal is to create new xls file and write to it.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("OpenXmlPowerTools")

Import-Module (join-path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) "GenericMethods.psm1")

$document = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument]::Create("C:\Temp\text.xlsx", [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType]::Workbook)

$workbookPart = $document.AddWorkbookPart();
$workbookPart.Workbook = New-Object -TypeName DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook

$worksheetPart = Invoke-GenericMethod -InputObject $workbookPart -MethodName AddNewPart -GenericType DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorksheetPart
$sheetData = New-Object -TypeName DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData
$worksheetPart.Worksheet = New-Object -TypeName DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet -ArgumentList $sheetData

[DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets]$foo = New-Object -TypeName DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets
Invoke-GenericMethod -InputObject $document.WorkbookPart.Workbook -MethodName AppendChild -GenericType DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets -ArgumentList $foo

$document.Close()
```

The problem is that this piece of code

```
[DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets]$foo = New-Object -TypeName DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets
Invoke-GenericMethod -InputObject $document.WorkbookPart.Workbook -MethodName AppendChild -GenericType DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets -ArgumentList $foo
```

throws error `Invoke-GenericMethod : No matching method was found`. Throws because `New-Object` creates something that is treated as empty array by `Invoke-GenericMethod` function. So the module is looking for generic methods with no parameters. Note thet first call to `Invoke-GenericMethod` is working fine.

How should I call `Invoke-GenericMethod` with `-ArgumentList` parameter?

Comment: `-ArgumentList (,$foo)`?

Comment: `Invoke-GenericMethod` is not a built-in PowerShell commandlet.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18774889/1001100) for more information.

Comment: @PetSerAl It's worked. But I can't understand why. And now empty object is returned by invoked method.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy I'm aware that this is not built-in function, I've said that in the question. The question you reffered is about parameterless methods wich is not my interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement` class (base class for `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets`) implement `IEnumerable` interface. That makes PowerShell interpret any instance of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets` as collection, rather than singular object.

When you write just

```
$foo
```

PowerShell will enumerate collection and display child elements instead (to be precise, you will see child of the child, because formatting cmdlets normally do another enumeration of collections). And since you just created this object, it will be empty and nothing will be displayed.

To actually display `$foo` object itself, you need to write it like this:

```
,$foo | Format-Table -Expand CoreOnly
```

or

```
,,$foo
```

The fact, that PowerShell interpret instance of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets` as collection, also affects how conversion to `[Object[]]` (type of `-ArgumentList` parameter) done. Instead of wrapping into single element array (as you want to call method with single argument), as it happens for singular objects, PowerShell create array from collection's elements.

To solve your issue you need to do wrapping into single element array by yourself. You can do that with unary comma oprator:

```
-ArgumentList (,$foo)
```