# How to call a generic method in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, generics, flaui

I created a dll in C# and then called this dll in PowerShell. Below I have a method called `TypeName<T>()`

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public string TypeName<T>() where T : FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.AutomationElement
    {
        return typeof(T).FullName;
    }
}
```

I'm using the FlaUI.Core reference from Nuget, that is, I'm just going to expect types from this reference:

```
where T : FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.AutomationElement
```

In Powershell, how do I call this generic method? I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
add-type -path C:\Users\unknow\source\repos\AutomationDLL\AutomationDLL\bin\Debug\My.dll
add-type -path C:\Users\unknow\source\repos\AutomationDLL\AutomationDLL\bin\Debug\FlaUI.Core.dll
add-type -path C:\Users\unknow\source\repos\AutomationDLL\AutomationDLL\bin\Debug\FlaUI.UIA3.dll

$instance = new-object ClassTest    
$instance.TypeName[[FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Button]]();
```

It is giving this error:

```
On line:7 character:59
+ $instance.TypeName[[FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Button]]();
+ ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
On line:7 character:60
+ $instance.TypeName[[FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Button]]();
+~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a parameterless generic method from Powershell v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774889/how-do-i-call-a-parameterless-generic-method-from-powershell-v3)

Comment: @Charlieface, we originally had that as a duplicate, but decided against it, given that the question at hand at least seemingly tries to use the new v7.3+-only syntax for invoking generic method withs explicit type arguments, whereas the linked question is about v3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only **PowerShell (Core) 7.3+** supports **calling
generic methods with *explicit* type arguments** - however, use only *enclosing* `[…]` - do not also enclose the type argument(s) in `[…]`:

```bash
# PS 7.3+ only
# Note: Only *one* set of [...], around the list of all type arguments,
#       not also around the individual type(s).
[ClassTest]::new().TypeName[FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Button]()
```

See the conceptual [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calling_Generic_Methods) help topic.

---

In **PowerShell 7.2-** (including in *Windows PowerShell*), **direct calls to generic methods are only possible if the type argument(s) can be *inferred*** from the *parameter values* (arguments), because these versions have *no* syntax for specifying type arguments explicitly.

**Otherwise** - such as in your case, given that your method has *no* parameters (other than a *type* parameter) -  you must **use *reflection***:

```bash
$instance = [ClassTest]::new()
[ClassTest].
  GetMethod('TypeName', [type[]] @()).
  MakeGenericMethod([FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Button]).
  Invoke($instance, @())
```

- `.GetMethod('TypeName', [type[]] @())` finds the overload of method `TypeName` that has *no parameters* (`[type[]] @()`) - since there is only *one* overload in your case, you could omit the second argument.
- `.MakeGenericMethod([…])` instantiates the method with the desired type argument.
- `.Invoke($instance, @())` then invokes the type-instantiated method on instance `$instance` with no arguments (`@()`, the empty array).